# Wanted to call a function in one file where definition of the function is in other file

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to call a function defined in a first.js file in second.js file. both files are defined in an HTML file like:

I want to call fn1() defined in first.js in second.js. From my searches answers were if first.js is defined first it is possible but from my tests I haven't found any way to do that. Thanks

Edit:
Here's sample codes:
**second.js**

```
this.getSecEnabled = function(){   ----> i dont know how this is used here..
     return SecEnabled;
}
```

**first.js**

```
if( getSecEnabled() == "SecEnabled" ){
    alert(" Security Enabled....!!");
}else{
        alert(" Secuity Disbaled.!!");
}
```

Issue : not able to print any of the statements here Enabled/Disabled.

Please help i am new to javascript

Answer (score 3):

Try loading second.js prior to first.js

Comment: remove 'this' from your function. so in second.js it should be: var getSecEnabled = function(){     return SecEnabled;
}

also, I dont know where SecEnabled is comming from. Is it defined else where?

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you don't want to wait until document is loaded then you have to load scripts in the following order:

- second.js
- first.js

But if you will change code of the second to execute when document will be ready then you can load scripts in any order.

[How to run script when document is ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t)

Comment: Could you please check whether condition is proper in first.js? is it something like this? because i am getting error here in this line ...
if( this.getSecEnabled() == "SecEnabled" ){

Script not going forward after this line

Comment: Please change it to :
getSecEnabled = function(){ 
     return 'SecEnabled';
}

Because you did not declared variable with name SecEnabled

Comment: you want to change the definition of funtion ?? which is in second.js which we should touch i belive, 
we can do changes in conditional statement. Please let me know changes in the condition of first.js

Comment: But you have error in the getSecEnabled or you didn't paste whole file. As I said there is no definition of SecEnabled variable and this is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Most of the latest browsers support ECMAScript modules out of the box. All you need to do is :

Make sure all of them are linked in your browser like this :

```
<script src="./path/to/script1.js" type="module" />
```

Now you can do something like this :

*script1.js*

```
   export function getSecEnabled (){   
     return SecEnabled;
}
```

*script2.js*

```
 import { getSecEnabled } from 'path/to/script1.js';

if( getSecEnabled() == "SecEnabled" ){
    alert(" Security Enabled....!!");
}else{
        alert(" Secuity Disbaled.!!");
}
```

Comment: Could you please check whether condition is proper in first.js? is it something like this? because i am getting error here in this line ...
if( this.getSecEnabled() == "SecEnabled" ){

Script not going forward after this line

Comment: you don't need to write `this` -
 
just write `getSecEnabled() == "SecEnabled"` since now you have access to the function, since you imported it in the top of the file.

Comment: i tried like as below as well with out this statement.

if( getSecEnabled() == "SecEnabled" ){
still failed to go forward of execution

Answer (score 0):

I have a function called include().

What this function does is tell the browser to load a file , then do an action .

So , the action can only be done AFTER the file is loaded .

So in your case ; we will first include first.js then include second.js

So , second.js will run only AFTER first.js runs.

Here is the code  :

```
function include(file){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = file;
            script.type ='text/javascript';
            script.defer = true;
            document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(script);

            script.onload = function(){
            resolve()
            }
            script.onerror = function(){
              reject()
            }
          })

     /*I HAVE MODIFIED THIS TO  BE PROMISE-BASED 
       HOW TO USE THIS FUNCTION 

      include('js/somefile.js').then(function(){
      console.log('Do an action that depends on somefile.js');
      },function(){
      console.log('Do not do an action that depends on somefile.js');
      })
      */
    }



    include('first.js')
    .then(()=>{
      include('second.js');
    })
```